# Unable to submit a form with some js submit

Tags: javascript, java, html

This is an extension to my previous question available here [Webapp Not working only in Chrome, but working in FireFox and Eclipse Default Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741749/webapp-not-working-only-in-chrome-but-working-in-firefox-and-eclipse-default-br)

Rewriting my question. I'm coding a web application in java using jsp and Servlet. Basically there are 2 buttons one is enabled at first and 2nd one is disabled, when I click the first button, there is a textbox populated with some text and the submit gets enable disabling the first button. for this task I've written a Javascript and below is how it looks.

```
<body>
<form method="get" action="GetData">
            <input type="Submit" value="Get Case" name="getCase" id="getCase"
                onclick="enableSubmit()" />
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input id="Text1" type="text" readonly value="" /></td>
.
.
.
.
.
.
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function enableSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
        }
        function enableGetCase() {
            document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

When I run this program in my Firefox/eclipse default browser, the data is correctly picked up. But when I run the same in my Chrome, the data is not picked up from database. Just the button gets enabled. But I observed something today while doing trial/error method. when I disable the below code block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function enableSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false;
        }
        function enableGetCase() {
            document.getElementById("getCase").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
```

The chrome picks up the data(the second button is not enabled, since I've removed that code block). Can some one please let me know how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you kindly check the errors in the console by pressing `F12` button?

Comment: There are no errors in this place